# flask-sqlalchemy table edits aren't showing up

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is probably a super basic question, but I'm just getting started with Flask and have run into a wall. I can add a table to a db (currently using sqlite) and it's visible to other connections to the database instantly, but any edits don't show up for a minute or so.

I have the table:

```
class Sequence(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sequence'
    __searchable__ = ['sequence','notes']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique = True)
    sequence = db.Column(db.String())
    notes = db.Column(db.String())
```

I'm using WTForms to create a form that is then parsed for both adding and editing.

My code for adding an entry is:

```
@app.route('/add_sequence', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_sequence():
    form = SequenceForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_sequence = form.sequence_from_form()
        db.session.add(new_sequence)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Added new sequence: ' + form.name.data)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Whereas my code for editing an entry is:

```
@app.route('/edit_sequence/<sequence_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_sequence(sequence_id):
    form = SequenceForm()
    sequence = Sequence.query.filter_by(id=sequence_id).first()
    if sequence == None:
        return render_template('sequence_not_found.html')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        sequence.name = form.name.data
        sequence.sequence = form.sequence_data.data
        sequence.notes = form.notes.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('modified sequence ' + sequence.name)
        return redirect(url_for('show_sequence',sequence_id=sequence_id))
    else:
        form.fill_from_sequence(sequence)
        return render_template('edit_sequence.html',form=form, sequence_id=sequence_id)
```

Any additions made using add_sequence show up instantly to any other db connections, but changes made using the second entry aren't immediately visible.

Comment: You are missing the `db.session.add()` call in the second code example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the updated sequence obj to the database session

```
@app.route('/edit_sequence/<sequence_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_sequence(sequence_id):
    form = SequenceForm()
    sequence = Sequence.query.filter_by(id=sequence_id).first()
    if sequence == None:
        return render_template('sequence_not_found.html')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        sequence.name = form.name.data
        sequence.sequence = form.sequence_data.data
        sequence.notes = form.notes.data
        db.session.add(sequence) #adding object to session
        db.session.commit()
        flash('modified sequence ' + sequence.name)
        return redirect(url_for('show_sequence',sequence_id=sequence_id))
    else:
        form.fill_from_sequence(sequence)
        return render_template('edit_sequence.html',form=form, sequence_id=sequence_id)
```

and you can edit the sequence object by using [update cluase](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update)

```
 db.session.query(Sequence).filter_by(id=sequence_id).update({'name': form.name.data,'sequence' : form.sequence_data.data, 'notes' : form.notes.data })
 db.session.commit()
```

Comment: This seems to have worked!  I didn't see anything in the documentation about update() being preferable to editing the object directly then committing. Anyone know if this is possibly a sqlite specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the problem I was having seems to have been due to a bug in Flask-WhooshAlchemy, which is described in some detail here: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling

I haven't tried implementing the fix described, but removing the whoosh indexing from my code made my original implementation work. The use of update() also seemed to work, however I ran into problems when I would try to delete an entry from the database.